# Difficulty installing program through makefile: "Are the same file"

Tags: compiling, make, makefile

I am attempting to install a CFD code called MISES on my ubuntu system, but every time I try to make the file, it generates a bunch of .o files then fails with the following output:

```
install -s ises ../bin/
install: 'ises' and '../bin/ises' are the same file
Makefile:213: recipe for target 'ises' failed
make: *** [ises] Error 1
```

The lines specified in the error are these:

```
ises:   $(ISESOBJ)
$(FC) -o ises $(ISESOBJ) $(FTNLIB)
$(INSTALL) ises $(BIN)
```

Looking for a solution to this problem on the forum suggests that the $(prefix) variable may not be defined, but I have been unable to figure out what that means for this problem and system.

If I change the definition of the bin path from the one provided in the makefile, the make will complete.  When this happens, shared library files are placed in the new folder, but the program does not run when called in the terminal (as expected from the documentation).

A colleague has used this makefile before on another system, so I know that it works, but I am unsure how to get it to work on my system.

Comment: It sounds like you set the install prefix to be the same as the root of the source tree you are trying to build - it's hard to say more without seeing the steps you took up to this point

Comment: I'm not sure if this clarifies anything, but the directory definitions are: BIN = /home/codes/bin/ ; FTNLIB = ; ISESOBJ = (lots of .o files) $(BLOBJ) $(LNOBJ)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was the bin location.  Changing the bin path allows the make to complete, and the codes will run as long as they are called using a path (i.e. ../codes/ises).